# Getting to run code a specific number of times selected from a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have an instant variable (`@number`) attached to a drop down array of numbers (1..10). I want my block of code that I have in my HTML to generate that one block of code, however many times the specific number was selected

# for example.

```
<% @number.times do %>
  <div> class = (row) 'HTML code'>
    <[image]>
  <div/>
<% end %>
```

I've tried to run this code in my `html.erb` file and I keep getting an error saying `undefined .times`.
I'm very new to ruby and code but I heard `.times` is similar to `.each` which is ruby language, and I've also defined in my controller parameters to my instant variable `@number` and even tried to assign an integer of `.to_i` to it.....any suggestions would be appreciated ;)

Comment: Pls put the complete error message, my bet is that @number is not an integer.

Comment: undefined method `times' for "6":String
Extracted source (around line #1):
1
2
3
4
5
6

Comment: <% @team_number.times do %>

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells me your @number variable contains a string. Either make sure you assign a numeric value to it in the first place or transform it to a number prior to calling `times`:

```
@number.to_i.times
```

You wrote above that .to_i didn't work for you though - do you get the same error message then?